# How to Publish RSS feeds Automatically in my site

Tags: php, rss, feed

How to generate / Publish RSS feeds Automatically Using PHP in my site. So that the user can consume the updates frequently without any manual efforts.

Comment: This is not a question, just two statements with the presumption that a reader will be able to pick a question out of them.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is incredibly vague in terms of specific details I'll take a stab at it.

Normally an Atom / RSS feed is used to broadcast new content. Blog posts, comments, articles and the like. The easiest way to do this is place include a `/feed` url that loads up a PHP page. This page will go through a predetermined number (10, 20, 30, etc) of recent entries and output them in well formed XML. Readers will check this url periodically for new content.

Comment: My query is "How to Broadcast the RSS feeds from my website contents?". Are there any specific free tools available?

Comment: @user616440: And there are plenty of tools **if you have a specific idea of what content you are trying to public**. I'm giving you general direction, be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

java, php and javascript? no matter the language it is basically xml in a certain format. there must be more than 1 million tutorials on this subject. Instead of echoing the data in html tags, use the xml tags and set the correct header

http://www.w3schools.com/rss/default.asp

The standard https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822

Answer (score 0):

You can use this PHP Class  [RSS Writer class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/560-PHP-XML-RSS-feed-generator-for-content-syndication-.html)